# Auth0 Token Endpoint Authentication Method is faded out?

Tags: auth0

I am suppose to change this field inside my client settings to something other than none, but it is greyed out and I cannot change it. Is there something else I have to do? 
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will be intentionally greyed out if you have a Client Type of "Single Page Application" or "Native" as it does not make sense for those types. See below:

[image]

If your application were "Regular Web App" or "Non Interactive Client" this would become available.

Comment: Great to hear, thanks for acknowledging, appreciate it.